# Symfony2 Doctrine multiple manyToMany Releationships between same entity, yml file

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml

I currently have a manyToMany relationship that works correctly.  I want to add a second manyToMany relationship between the same entities.  However doctrine/symphony tries to create a table with the same name causing an error.  How do i add the second relationship?

YML file original relationship

```
...
manyToMany:
    originFormDataObjects:
        targetEntity: SM\FormBundle\Entity\FormData
        mappedBy: targetFormDataObjects
        orderBy: { 'id': 'DESC' }
    targetFormDataObjects:
        targetEntity: SM\FormBundle\Entity\FormData
        inversedBy: originFormDataObjects
        orderBy: { 'id': 'DESC' }
```

YML file with added relationship, causing an error

```
...
manyToMany:
    originFormDataObjects:
        targetEntity: SM\FormBundle\Entity\FormData
        mappedBy: targetFormDataObjects
        orderBy: { 'id': 'DESC' }
    targetFormDataObjects:
        targetEntity: SM\FormBundle\Entity\FormData
        inversedBy: originFormDataObjects
        orderBy: { 'id': 'DESC' }
    formDataObjects:
        targetEntity: SM\FormBundle\Entity\FormData
```

Comment: What is the error it is throwing?

Comment: "   The table with name 'ilossrep_sm_dev1.formdata_formdata' already exists." is the error

Answer (score 0):

You could try specifying the table name, like this:

```
manyToMany:
originFormDataObjects:
    targetEntity: SM\FormBundle\Entity\FormData
    mappedBy: targetFormDataObjects
    orderBy: { 'id': 'DESC' }
    joinTable:
      name: table_name
      joinColumns:
        fk_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
      inverseJoinColumns:
        inverse_id:
          referencedColumnName: id
```